# How to Remove Google Analytics JS code from Wordpress blog. Can't pinpoint location

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to remove the following code located on my wordpress blog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-00000-1']); 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-0000000-1']); 
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'ohloh.net']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'http://' : 'http://www') +  
 '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

I've been doing a lot of research online as to where to find it but so far my leads have gone up dry.

Here was how I started. Under Appearances and editor, I clicked on my footer.php code under templates which gives me this code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Footer Template
 *
 * Here we setup all logic and XHTML that is required for the footer section of all screens.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
 ?>


<?php include('xxxx-footer-canvas.php');?>
```

```
<div id="footer" class="col-full">

    <?php woo_footer_inside(); ?>    

    <div id="copyright" class="col-left">
        <?php woo_footer_left(); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="credit" class="col-right">
        <?php woo_footer_right(); ?>
    </div>

</div><!-- /#footer  -->

<?php woo_footer_after(); ?>    

</div><!-- /#wrapper -->

<div class="fix"></div><!--/.fix-->

<?php woo_foot(); ?>

<?php endif; ?> <!--END of REMOVE ******************************************-->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
```

Next, from the code above I saw that I needed to look under xxxx-footer.php for the content. There was a log of content on the xxx-footer.php fie but nothing that led me towards the location (I could post some of the contents if relevant).

I've deduced that the problem is in this function called  taken from the footer.php in templates. I confirmed it by removing this function call and the code disappeared. However, this code removed more than just the tracking code. Now what I'm trying to do is pinpoint the location of this but my leads have gone dry.

Additonally, I've looked under functions.php, functions.wp-scripts.php, general-template.php with no luck.

I have no plugins that would indicate that the code comes with a plugin. The current plugins I have are:

- AddThis Social Bookmarking Widget
- Akismet
- AP Extended Mime Types
- Broken Link Checker
- Contact Form 7
- Disqus Comment System
- Hello Dolly
- Improved Include Page
- Polldaddy Polls & Ratings
- pType Converter
- Q and A FAQ and Knowledge Base for WordPress
- Raw HTML
- Ultimate TInyMCE
- WordPress Importer
- WordPress Move
- WP Show IDs

Where could this code possibly be? Help would be appreciated.

- I also posted this on wordpress support forums too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was a theme you got/purchased, most likely the analytics is set up in the theme settings that you can override. Otherwise, I would suggest you look in your FTP for a full structure of the theme files. Sometimes theme developers break down the code further than you can see in just the WordPress appearance editor (same goes for plugins). WordPress will not see folders in there.

Anything more you can post will lead me to a more specific and detailed answer. I can also assist in explaining how to remove functions without breaking down everything.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How would I go about customizing the theme settings or override them? Also, I do have my FTP tree up and running and I can see the files. I've been trying to use the grep command to find google code and it seems to derive from this .txt file.
/wp-content/themes/canvas/cache/timthumb_int_6db59e359f32ff3bc0c36daaa3addf72.timthumb.txt: Permission denied.

Comment: Make sure your site wasn't hacked. If you use TimThumb there was a huge vulnerability found:http://wptavern.com/wordpress-security-alert-new-zero-day-vulnerability-discovered-in-timthumb-script Theme setting locations are either under Appearance or in their own menu. It depends on the theme and how the developer chose to set it up.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help Aibrean. I actually didn't need to look under the hood. All I needed to do was click on the Canvas setting and then remove the tracking code. It was actually very simple. Thank again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The source is probably Disqus. I am facing the same issue with a non-WP site, and I have tracked the source down to Disqus (being loaded from an iframe that was created by Disqus code). From what I have read, thus far, it appears that it is integrated into Disqus, and there seems to be no information about disabling GA from Disqus.

I, for one, am considering moving away from Disqus if GA cannot be disabled when using Disqus.